# Vuetify.js: how to place button actions in v-card on left and right?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In `v-card-actions` component of `v-card`, I want to  place one button on the left and the other on the right using `mr-0` (margin-right= 0), but the 2 buttons always stay close to each other.

What I tried:

- Prop `left` and `right` for the buttons
- `v-spacer` component between the buttons

Code:

```
<v-card>
  <v-card-title primary-title>
    <div>
      <h3 class="headline mb-0">Ttile</h3>
      <div>Located two hours south of Sydney in the <br>Southern Highlands of New South </div>
    </div>
  </v-card-title>

  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn left>Share</v-btn>
    <v-spacer />
    <v-btn right>Explore</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/XxQdEv?editors=1010).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your code is correct. Just use this:

```html
<v-card-actions>
  <v-btn>Share</v-btn>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-btn>Explore</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

Change the `v-spacer` to not be self-enclosing tag.

Comment: That is strange, I though `v-spacer` is a self closed component. Thank you

Comment: That's weird, self-enclosing notation works for me (using Vueitfy 2.4.0).

Comment: @Haltarys strange. See this CodePen ⇾ https://codepen.io/Roland1993/pen/qBmZKJP?editors=1011 where it doesn't work even in 2.4.0.

Answer (score 15):

Just wrap them in `v-flex` and add `text-xs-right` class to the second, to pull to the right the second button.

```
<v-card-actions>
    <v-flex>
      <v-btn>Share</v-btn>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex class="text-xs-right">
      <v-btn>Explore</v-btn>
    </v-flex>
</v-card-actions>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJwrdK?editors=1010)

---

**Edit Vuetify 2.1.0** (thanks to @J. Unkrass) :

Just wrap them in `v-col` and add `text-right` class to the second, to pull to the right the second button.

```
<v-card-actions>
    <v-col>
      <v-btn>Share</v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col class="text-right">
      <v-btn>Explore</v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-card-actions>
```

Comment: I'm using Vuetify 2.1.0 and since one of the latter updates, `text-xs-right` should now be `text-right`, since the xs no longer needs to be specified. If you want to start using this at sm width, you can use `text-sm-right`and upwards.

Hope this will help someone, as I struggled with that at first after the update.

Comment: Also I think `<v-flex>` should now be `<v-col>` but `<v-flex>`still works fine.